# Infinite loop while gathering datasets from several worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first time to code in VBA. 
I have several worksheets in a file and they are in order by dates.
So what I am trying to do is to collect data sets in a worksheet if they have the same period of time.

date1 value1
date2 value2
date3 value3

Since they are in order I just compare the first date values and if they are different it moves on to the next worksheet. If they are the same then copy the value and do the same process until it reaches the last worksheet.
However it copies one worksheet fine but after that Excel freezes.

I would be appreciated if you find any errors or give me other suggestions to do it.
Following is my code:

```
Sub matchingStock()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
' create short references to sheets
' inside the Sheets() use either the tab number or name
Set sh1 = Sheets("combined")

Dim col As Long

'since first column is for Tbill it stock price should place from the third column
col = 3

Dim k As Long

'go through all the stock worksheets
For k = Sheets("WLT").Index To Sheets("ARNA").Index
    Set sh2 = Sheets(k)

    ' Create iterators
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    ' Create last rows values for the columns you will be comparing
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long

    ' create a reference variable to the next available row
    Dim nxtRow As Long

    ' Create ranges to easily reference data
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    ' Assign values to variables
    lr1 = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If sh1.Range("A3").Value = sh2.Range("A3").Value Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        ' Loop through column A on sheet1
        For i = 2 To lr1
            Set rng1 = sh1.Range("A" & i)

            ' Loop through column A on sheet1
            For j = 2 To lr2
                Set rng2 = sh2.Range("A" & j)

                ' compare the words in column a on sheet1 with the words in column on sheet2
                'Dim date1 As Date
                'Dim date2 As Date

                'date1 = TimeValue(sh1.Range("A3"))
                'date2 = TimeValue(sh2.Range("A3"))

                sh1.Cells(1, col).Value = sh2.Range("A1").Value

                ' find next empty row
                nxtRow = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                ' copy the word in column A on sheet2 to the next available row in sheet1
                ' copy the value ( offset(0,1) Column B ) to the next available row in sheet1
                sh1.Cells(nxtRow, col).Value = rng2.Offset(0, 6).Value

                'when the date is different skip to the next worksheet
                Set rng2 = Nothing
            Next j
            Set rng1 = Nothing
        Next i
        'sh3.Rows("1:1").Delete
        Else
            GoTo Skip
        End If
Skip:
col = col + 1
Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see what is actually happening?  How many rows are you talking about in each sheet?

Comment: As @gtwebb suggested, you need to see what loop is the culprit as you have several in your code.  My guess is that lr1 / lr2 are less than 2 on the next sheet.

Comment: I have about 1000 rows in each sheet

Answer (score 0):

I cannot identify a specific error so this is a list of suggestions that may help you identify the error and may help improve your code.

**Suggestion 1**

Do you think the Else block of If-Then-Else-End-If is compulsory?

```
  If sh1.Range("A3").Value = sh2.Range("A3").Value Then
    :
  Else
    GoTo Skip
  End If
Skip:
```

is the same as:

```
  If sh1.Range("A3").Value = sh2.Range("A3").Value Then
    :
  End If
```

**Suggestion 2**

I do not like:

```
For k = Sheets("WLT").Index To Sheets("ARNA").Index
```

The value of property Index for a worksheet may not what you think it is.  This may not give you the set or sequence of worksheets you expect.  Do you want every worksheet except "Combined"?  The following should be more reliable:

```
For k = 1 To Worksheets.Count
  If Worksheets(k).Name <> sh1.Name Then
    :
  End If
Next
```

**Suggestion 3**

You use:

```
.Range("A" & Rows.Count)
.Range("A3")
.Cells(1, col).Value
.Cells(Rows.Count, col)
rng2.Offset(0, 6)
```

All these methods of identifying a cell or a range have their purposes.  However, I find it confusing to use more than one at a time.  I find `.Cells(row, column)` and `.Range(.Cells(row1, column1), .Cells(row2, column2))` to be the most versatile and use them unless there is a powerful reason to use one of the other methods.

**Suggestion 4**

I cannot decypher what this code is attempting to achieve.

You say: "I have several worksheets in a file and they are in order by dates. So what I am trying to do is to collect data sets in a worksheet if they have the same period of time."

If you have set `Worksheet("combined").Range("A3").Value` to a particular date and you want to collect data from all those sheets with the same value in cell A3 then the outer For-Loop and the If give this effect.  But if so, if does not matter how the worksheets are ordered.  Also you start checking cell values from row 2 which suggests row 3 is a regular data row.

The outer loop is for each worksheet, the next loop is for each row in "combined" and the inner loop is for each row in the worksheet selected by the outer loop.  The middle loop does not appear to do anything but set `rng1` which is not used.

Perhaps you can add an explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

**Suggestion 5**

Are you trying to add an entire column of values from the source worksheets to "Combined".  The macro below:

- Identifies the next free row in column A of "Combined"
- Identifies the last used row in column A of "Sheet2"
- Assumes the first interesting row of "Sheet2" is 2.
- Adds the entire used range of column A of "Sheet2" (complete with formatting) to the end of "Combined"'s column A in a single statement.

This may demonstrate a better way of achieving the effect you seek.

```
Sub Test()

  Dim RngSrc As Range
  Dim RngDest As Range
  Dim RowCombNext As Long
  Dim RowSrcFirst As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long

  With Worksheets("Combined")
    RowCombNext = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set RngDest = .Cells(RowCombNext, "A")
  End With

  With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    RowSrcFirst = 2
    RowSrcLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngSrc = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcFirst, "A"), .Cells(RowSrcLast, "A"))
  End With

  RngSrc.Copy Destination:=RngDest

End Sub
```